# Search Bing News API for last 24 hours news

Tags: azure, bing, bing-api, azure-cognitive-services

I've just started working on Bing's search news api in my Java project. My requirment is to search bing once in a day to capture last 24 hours news for a given search term. In documention, I did not find any query parameter to set this time duration.

Can you please suggest a way to do it?

Query: https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search?q=accenture&safeSearch=Moderate

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **&freshness=day** url parameter to get news articles discovered within the last 24 hours. Consult the [News API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760793.aspx) for other capabilities supported by the News Search API.